# The proper use of Quotes with parenthesis, brackets, and braces

Tags: quotes, braces

"{bla bla bla}"

Do the quote marks go inside or outside the braces.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It's rather unclear to me what you're asking. Why would you ever need to place a parenthetical by itself inside quotes? Why would you ever use curly braces; what do they signify? Which style guide is the standard by which the text is being written? Please provide the context for the question, and a real example of the text as you would write it or as you have seen it written. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance on writing good, answerable questions.

Comment: If you are quoting a segment of text that begins and ends with a curly bracket symbol, then the form you have given in your question above is the most sensible way to do it; if the brackets are your addition to a quotation that for some reason you felt should be enclosed in brackets, then the opposite form—namely, {"blah blah blah"}—makes more sense to me. But as choster comments, your question as it stands is difficult to interpret and answer with any confidence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's been nagging at me. The braces are a part of a syntax I build throughout the piece.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little perplexed about the curly braces; they seem to be superfluous.

Here's how I would do it:

```
Bob: "There seems to be a problem." 
Dan: "It's about time you checked in. What's up?" 
Bob: "I don't know where to put these dang quotes." 
He shook his head. *Bob's a ninny*. "Can somebody answer Bob's question?" 
Dan: "Switch to nine for chit chat. Channel one is only for REAL emergencies"
```

And *Bob's a ninny* would benefit from some indication that it was a thought, not spoken.  *He shook his head and thought "Bob's a ninny."*  Or something like that.

Another thing that perplexes me about this is why do you think a radio conversation has to be blocked-out like this?  Why can't it be handled just like any other conversation (with he-said, she said, etc.), while making clear the medium of the conversation when it begins?

Comment: A further problem is that in the dialogue between Bob and Dan, only Bob's voice seems to be arriving via radio; Dan (as nearly as I can tell) is one of the people at the command base or headquarters or whatever it is who are wondering why Bob hasn't checked in. Although Dan communicates with Bob via radio, his voice in the scene would be heard as an in-person voice, not an over-the-radio voice.